# Changed edit still doesn't compile

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

Yesterday I edited [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1389514/2420536). The main reason for my edit was that the code does not compile (since the `Interlocked.CompareExchange` method does not have an overload taking two arguments see [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx)). I explained this in the edit reason.

However, to reach the minimum edit length of 6 characters, I then proceeded to add some markup and try to make the answer more readable.

Now I see that my edit was [changed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1389514/revisions), but no longer includes the fix to the code! What is my recourse?

Comment: I'm confused. You say the method doesn't have an overload taking three arguments, yet all of the signatures for that method have three arguments.

Comment: Sorry, yes a typo on my part here. If you refer to the question you will see that the method is called with two arguments in the code snippet, but I changed it to use three as documented.

Comment: Yes, but your typo is also in the edit summary. So for someone paying attention it looks like your deliberately introducing a third argument while asserting that with a third argument, the code won't work.

Comment: Ah, thank you so I made the same typo twice.
But my code should work, and I believe that it serves the intended purpose.

Comment: Actually, renaming method from `CompareExchange` to simple `Exchange` would also make the answer valid... So edit you propose is not the only valid one. In that case it is better to not edit *other's* code at all. Just leave a comment, as suggested in @Maroun Maroun's answer. (And you have already done that, I see).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Don't** make changes to code. If I were reviewing your edit, I would have rejected it even without the markup changes.

If you think OP has an error in his code, you can suggest a fix in the *comments* section and not trying to modify the code, and if the answer is wrong you may downvote and explain it.